# Java Boolean and function not working

Tags: java

Ok everyone am sure this is a simple fix.

```
public class function {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        public boolean playButton = true;
        public boolean playMusic() {
            if (playButton) {
                System.out.println("Music"); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Music");
            }
    }
}
```

all i want is for the terminal to print out music.

Comment: move the `playMusic` method out of the `main` method

Comment: You cannot define a method within a method; this code does not even compile to begin with. What did you expect exactly?

Comment: I know the code is a bit out of wack, could you show me a proper alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class function {
    public static boolean playButton = true;
    public static void playMusic() {
            if (playButton == true) {
                System.out.println("Music"); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Music");
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       playMusic()
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation or text is a low quality answer

Comment: If we where at a bar right now I'd buy you a bottle and walk away. Big Thanks Sir.

Comment: I was about deleting it when i saw someone already gave an answer that works just like mine. before you guys downvoted me

Comment: It's fine to answer even if someone already answered, but at least add some text :) Don't mean to be rude, just to drive SO to have high quality Q/A

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your 'playMusic' function outside 'main' method and call it from main, try something like this:

```
public class function {
    static boolean playButton;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        playButton = true;
        playMusic();
    }
    public static void playMusic() {
        if (playButton) {
            System.out.println("Music"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Music");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't actually return a boolean from anywhere in playMusic, or appear to have any use for one. Change to void?